# How to use Eigen as third party library in Unreal Engine 5?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I'm trying to include Eigen in UE5 - there's some old UE4 documentation on this but it produces a different plugin file.

It looks like UE5 includes Eigen under Engine/Source/ThirdParty/Eigen/, but the actual library does not seem to be there. So, I tried to add a new plugin using the UE5 editor (called 'ThirdParty'), include the Eigen source manually under Plugins/ThirdParty/Source/Eigen/, and add the path references i.e.:

```
    PublicIncludePaths.AddRange(
        new string[] {
            "Eigen",
        }
        );
```

However, this does not seem to work, as #include 'Eigen/Dense' or just 'Eigen' results in an error in the rest of my project. Any ideas? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Unreal Engine 5 all you should need to do is add

AddEngineThirdPartyPrivateStaticDependencies(Target,  "Eigen");

into your project or plugins Build.cs file, and you should be able to include the library using

#include <Eigen/Core>

as usual!